# I have to use "sudo" for almost every git / rails command or I get permission denied. How can I fix that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I'm learning rails and as I go through the process of creating the default app and connecting to github etc. I am forced to use sudo otherwise I get permission denied errors. I am the admin, I am the only user account on my computer.

Did I set something up incorrectly?

I even had this problem way back when trying to create/edit .bash_profile

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you probably have messed up the file ownerships of your rails app, try running (within your rails app directory!!!!)

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` .
```

Comment: I get: "chown: whoami: Invalid argument"

Comment: dont forget the backticks, or replace `\`whoami\`` with your username

Comment: Worked with my username, thank you. It didn't output anything, which I assume it what's supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

i had this before specially for rails commands and after installing [RVM](https://rvm.io/) I am not using sudo command anymore